# Textured leafy green in garden

Tags: identification

[image: Unidentified leafy green]

I have an unidentified leafy green in my garden. I'd like to know what it is as it's threatening to hedge in on my peas, which you can see a bit of in the right side of the photo.

I'm quite new to gardening, and since I'm coming to this garden bed second-hand, I'm not sure if it is a vegetable of some sort that the previous year's gardener put in.

The leaves have a texture very similar to a cucumber plant. My location is central Mississippi.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to tell, but it looks very similar to a dock.  I'm thinking a curly dock.  It's an edible "weed" (I use weed in the term that it's an unwanted plant in your garden) with many uses, but I would pull it out.  It has a large taproot, so you have to make sure you pull the whole thing or it will keep coming back.
[Voyageur Country Curled Dock](http://www.voyageurcountry.com/htmls/floweringplants/plants/dockcurled.html)

Answer (score 4):

It might also be sorrel (which is related to dock).  Pinch off a bit of one of the leaves and chew it.  If it is sorrel it will taste acidic, a bit like a lemon but not as much flavor.

Comment: I tasted it, but it doesn't have any taste I can really make out. Are sorrel leaves suppose to have the bristly texture?